# Why can't I save this website with cURL or Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I have a problem, I can save a lot of pages with Simple HTML DOM or cURL, but by this domain I can save just the half of the content and I don't know why.

When I print the the variable `$html` then I see the complete content of the page. The database field is a normal text field.

My Code:

```
include('config.php');
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.statistik-portal.de/Statistik-Portal/');;

mysql_query("UPDATE `kgs_test` SET `content` = '$html' WHERE `id` = 1");
```

The saved Code in my Database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de" xml:lang="de">  <head>  <title>Gemeinsames Datenangebot der Statistischen &Auml;mter des Bundes und der L&auml;nder</title>  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  <meta name="content-language" content="de" />  <meta name="description" content="Gemeinsames Datenangebot der Statistischen &Auml;mter des Bundes und der L&auml;nder" />  <meta name="author" content="Statistisches Landesamt Baden-W&uuml;rttemberg" />  <meta name="keywords" content="Daten, Bund, Land" />  <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, noarchive" />  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Statistik-Portal/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />  <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/Statistik-Portal/Suche/OpenSearch.xml" title="Amtl.Statistik" />  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Statistik-Portal/styleScreen.css" title="Standard" />  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/Statistik-Portal/stylePrint.css" />  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Statistik-Portal/styleScreenS.css" title="nur-Text" />    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3"/>    </head>    <body onload="window.focus()">    <p id="skipNav"><a href="#content">Navigation
```

When I try to save a page from a other domain with a lot of more lines of code, then I have no problems. If I try to save a subpage of this domain then the code stopped every time after the word "Navigation".

Comment: Please don't use snippets if the code isn't supposed to run in your post.

Comment: try to look at the source of the page using a browser, then analyze what comes after the word Navigation.

Comment: normal html -> überspringen</a></p>

Comment: @RemigiusStalder: That appears to be `ü`. Maybe the OP's database can't handle that? (Seems weird).

Comment: This is possible. What's the encoding of your database? What happens if you just output the content of $html (i.e. will it be visible or is it also cut after Navigation?

Comment: no, i have test it i can save a ü into the database field

Comment: @Remigius Stalder utf-8 i save a lot of content with üä letters into the same database

Comment: i solved the problem now with: $html = file_get_html('http://www.statistik-portal.de/Statistik-Portal/');;
$html = utf8_encode($html);
mysql_query("UPDATE `kgs_test` SET `content` = '$html' WHERE `id` = 1");